# How to know the origin resource group of a App Service Plan?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have an Azure App Service Plan and a Web App. I want to move them to another subscription. There is a limitation that app service plan and app service must be moved together from the origin resource group of the app service plan. Someone had moved the resources from their origin resource group and deleted the resource group. Now, how can I find the name of the origin resource group ?

In some cases it can be found in the WebSpace property of app service plan. For example [ "webSpace": "RG-SK-MarkIII-CentralUSwebspace" ], RG-SK-MarkIII is the origin resource group of the app plan. But in my case the webSpace is like this ["webSpace": "AustraliaEastwebspace" ]. Is there any other way to find it through CloudShell ?

Answer (score 0):

You can look up the [`actions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-audit) taken by a particular user, even for a resource group that no longer exists.

```
az monitor activity-log list -g ExampleGroup --caller someone@contoso.com --offset 5d
```

Comment: '-g' is unknown in my case and the deletion activity might had happened 1 year ago , what to do now ?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try these steps: 
If you don't remember the original resource group, you can find it through diagnostics.

- For your web app, select Diagnose and solve problems.

  Then, select Configuration and Management.

  Select Migration Options.

  Select the option for recommended steps to move the web app.

You see the recommended actions to take before moving the resources. The information includes the original resource group for the web app. 
- I understand you're referring to RG deletion scenario, kindly try this and let me know how it goes.

Reference document [move across subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/move-limitations/app-service-move-limitations#move-across-subscriptions).

Furthermore, you can only change to a plan that was created in the same "webspace" as your original app.  Webspace is an internal concept that's not exposed, but you can verify whether your source and destination plans are in the same webspace or not.

To verify, do the following:

1. https://resources.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/{serverFarmName}
2. Confirm whether the webSpace property of your source plan matches the webSpace property of your new plan